# While loop to linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is there any way to accumulate something using linq.

Initial code :

```
Something oneItem;
List<Something> allItems;
while ((oneLine = _generator.GenerateSomething()) != null)
    allItems.Add(_generator.CurrentItem);
```

I would like something like :

```
var allItems = Enumerable.Take( ()=>_generator.GenerateSomething()).While(item=>item !=null).ToList();
```

Actually, it would have been very good if generator implemented IEnumerable, I would have use it this way :

```
var allItems = _generator.TakeWhile(item !=null);
```

This last one is really easy to understand, I would like to approach it (I can use a kind of wrapper that generate a machine state given a production method (_generator.GenerateSomething()) and a stop condition (item == null). But I can not write this additional class for some reason).

Comment: why do you want this ?

Comment: I found the initial code quite messy, I would like something better written

Comment: The initial code elegantly expresses what is happening.  While Linq is the new Black, it's not always appropriate to wear black.

Comment: That code looks clear and concise to me.  Very maintainable.

Comment: @EricJ. The initial code is only easy for you to read because you're used to seeing it.  For someone unfamiliar with that particular idiom it's actually confusing to read, understand, debug, etc.  Using an idiom that is more in line with a linq-eque style of programming allows this code to be refactored into code that is much easier to work with.

Comment: NB : I changed a bit the question for a more general approach.

Comment: @Servy: Sorry, but I do not agree.  The "loop" idiom is one of the most basic idioms in software engineering.

Comment: I think Servy was referring to the side effect (assignment) within the loop condition.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: Having a loop affect something outside of the scope of the loop is also a rather common idiom...

Comment: @EricJ. It is in old C code, sure.  These days, and particularly in C#, it's far more commonly accepted as a good practice to avoid loop conditionals that cause side effects.  Again, you've used this idiom so much that you don't need to actually digest it to understand it, you can just remember it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a function that is an equivalent to `File.ReadLines` in concept.  Abstract away the code for reading lines from the console once, so that it can be reused.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLinesFromConsole()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var next = Console.ReadLine();
        if (next == null)
            yield break;
        yield return next;
    }
}
```

That said, if you *really* want to generalize it, you can.  What you have here is a simple generator accepting a function.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Generate<T>(Func<T> generator)
{
    while (true)
        yield return generator();
}
```

This allows you to write the code that you had in your example:

```
var allLines = Generate(() => Console.ReadLine())
    .TakeWhile(line => line != null);
```

Comment: @EricJ. When you never need to see it it's *irrelevant* how simple it is.  It's behind a black box.  That's the advantage of a black box, you're free to write it however you want, and do not need to focus on making the hidden code short, concise, etc.

Comment: @Servy: allLines is an `IEnumerable<string>`. You need a .ToList() on the end to get his original result.

Comment: @EricJ. If he really needs a list clearly he knows how to get one.  His edit indicates that that isn't even necessarily the case.  The decision is up to him whether or not he wants/needs to add it.

Comment: I think perhaps I don't fully understand the `yield` keyword, but what is the purpose of the `while(true)` here? Could it be removed?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien It's purpose is to loop unconditionally.  It is necessary here, otherwise each sequence would only ever have, at most, one value, and they need more than that.

Comment: Is there a danger of getting into a infinitive loop? It seems that only TakeWhile() is stopping this from happening. If we do `Generate(() => Console.ReadLine()).ToList()` without a TakeWhile() would that be a infinite list and throw an exception?

Comment: @LukeTO'Brien Yes, it's an infinite sequence.  The consumer of the sequence needs to either work property with an infinite sequence, or limit it to a finite sequence.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iterator method like this:

```
static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines()
{
    string line;
    while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != string.Empty)
        yield return line;
}
```

And this way you can stream it or call `ToList()` on it:

```
ReadAllLines().ToList();
```

Or filter on it:

```
ReadAllLines().Where(line => line.Contains("cool"));
```

Comment: too bad we can't have static extension methods.  Console.ReadLines would be nice!

Comment: Make an extension method for `TextReader`, then call it on `Console.In`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var lines = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x => Console.ReadLine()).TakeWhile(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe you should try it before posting.

Comment: I'm taking advantage of how Linq works, there's nothing hacky about that!

Comment: this is not taking advantage of anything. this is misusing of linq.

Comment: @Jonesy: It does not "create a throwaway object of 2 billion items". `Enumerable.YieldTrueForever` would work as well as a seed, if it existed.

Comment: It does not create 2 billion objects, you have to know how Linq works to understand that.

Comment: It adds a useless counter which of course doesnt really affect performance.

Comment: Of course, this won't work if the program actually needs to accept more than 2 billion lines of input data, given that it's not *actually* an infinite sequence.

Comment: @Selman22 In what way?  What aspects of this code are in violation of what principles of LINQ?  This code is in fact very much in line with a linq-est functional style of programming and is not in any way mis-using any of its features.  It's only real flaw, as I mentioned earlier, is that it doesn't *actually* have an infinite sequence when it intends to have one.  Well, that and a lack of line breaks, which is *super* annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible by exploiting deferred execution, but I doubt that it is more readable than your original solution:

```
var lines = (from _ in Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue)
             select Console.ReadLine())
            .TakeWhile(s => s != null)
            .ToList();
```

(It works because LINQ statements are not executed immediately and TakeWhile ensures that iteration stops in time.)

Answer (score 0):

And just to have yet another approach:

```
public static class FuncExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerabley<T> AsGenerator(this Func<T> func)
    {
        while(true) yield return func();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Func<string> f = Console.ReadLine;

f.AsGenerator().Select(...).ToList();

// this won't work unfortunately
Console.ReadLine.AsGenerator().Select(...)
```